# Is there a applet to switch desktop themes?

Tags: mate

I use mate and I want to be able to switch desktop themes with a single click. i.e from light to dark theme.
is there a way I could do this with shell script and what command do I use to change theme.

Comment: That is possible easily.. I am not using mate.. Experts using mate can give you the commands.. I am commenting this just to let you know its possible and very easy

Comment: @pmdun, it is great that my answer helped you to solve the problem. You can [accept the answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) to mark problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

I did not see such applet in the repositories.

But you can write your own by using *Custom Application Launcher*s:

- first may have command for dark theme - `sh -c "gsettings set org.mate.interface gtk-theme 'Ambiance' && gsettings set org.mate.interface icon-theme 'ubuntu-mono-dark' && gsettings set org.mate.Marco.general theme 'Ambiance'"`
- second may have command for light theme - `sh -c "gsettings set org.mate.interface gtk-theme 'Radiance' && gsettings set org.mate.interface icon-theme 'ubuntu-mono-light' && gsettings set org.mate.Marco.general theme 'Radiance'"`

Above is just an example. You can adapt it to your favorite theme names (check changes and config values with `gsettings list-recursive` and some diff-like application i.e. `meld`).